# Oracle DB SQL select variables with certain suffix

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is anyone know how to get all the columns of a table with a certain suffix?

Maybe something like:

select * from table_name where name like '%_cd';

Comment: _ is a wild card for any single character, presumably you want to escape it to find things like 'doubleSided_cd' ?

Comment: You're talking about "variables" which implies that you're referring to local variables defined in PL/SQL.  Your query, though, is hitting a particular table in the database which implies that you're not talking about variables but about data stored in a table.  Are you trying to list the columns of the table that end with "_cd"?  If so, you could potentially use dynamic SQL but whether that is useful will depend on what you're doing with the results and whether the caller can deal with a dynamic result set.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yes, I'm trying to get all the columns end with _cd

Comment: @JustinCave I'm sorry for the confusing. I'm trying to get all the columns end with _cd

Comment: You cannot do this directly. You can however build a dynamic SQL statement by querying column names from system table all_tab_cols.

Answer (score 0):

This will return all columns for the table `THE_TABLE` that end with `_CD`

```
select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where column_name like '%\_CD%' escape '\' 
  and table_name = 'THE_TABLE'
order by column_id;
```

Remember that Oracle stores table and column names in uppercase unless you quoted them using double quotes in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. Therefor you need `'%_CD'` and not `'%_cd%'`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you know how to get data of these columns then?

Comment: @PhoenixQ you need to create dynamic SQL based on that information. However this all sounds as if your data model could use some re-thinking

Comment: Maybe something like 'select (select column_name ...) from table_name'

Comment: @PhoenixQ no, that's not possible. Dynamic SQL is your *only* option.

Comment: I never worked on dynamic sql. Could you show me an example of how to figure out this issue with dynamic sql? btw, I'm using sql developer 4

Comment: Bit of effort guy http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#CHDGJEGD